# Is there a CLI IRC client with a GUI?

Tags: command-line, software-recommendation, irc

Some CLI apps, like htop, do a great job at providing you with a UI for configuring it. This way you can do some customizations just using the keyboard and/or mouse (!), without spending spending a lot of time reading arcane documentation, since GUIs are easily discoverable. It still provides command-line flags and a text configuration file for those who prefer it. In the end it's the best of both worlds. Example screenshot:

[image]

I was looking for a CLI IRC client, tried irssi and couldn't connect to my target server because I couldn't figure out how to whitelist the fingerprint of a self-signed SSL certificate on the server. I'm not looking for help with my irssi issue, to me this is just a taste of things to come: every time I'll want to do ANYTHING in irssi, I can expect to lose 10+ minutes reading doc, until I have mastered irssi. I don't want to do that. I just want to use IRC from the CLI as easily as possible.

I'm looking for the htop of IRC clients. Is there an IRC client for Ubuntu one can use and tweak in a GUI options screen, instead of being forced to master its custom text configuration file format/commands?

Answer (score 0):

After a good long search I can tell you that what you are after does not exist, although at one stage it did!

The [irssi FAQs](https://irssi.org/documentation/faq/) actually address this question for irssi itself:

> [−] Q: Where’s the GUI version?
>
> A: There was one on irssi-import/xirssi but it has not been maintained
> for a long time.

The application [xirssi](https://github.com/irssi-import/xirssi) unfortunately had its last good work done about 11 years ago and thus would be a poor choice indeed. All other command line interface IRC applications ask for all configuration to be done from, well, the CLI...

Don't forget that although it is *discouraged* you can alter the irssi configuration file: `$HOME/.irssi/config` with your favourite text editor and perhaps this would be a more palatable option for you...

Answer (score 0):

There's another terminal based IRC called WeeChat https://github.com/weechat/weechat